# $g = \gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a, c)$, then $\gcd(b,c) \geq g$, and give an example where $\gcd(b,c) > g$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Let $a, b, c$ be natural numbers and $g = \gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a, c)$, then $\gcd(b,c) \geq g$, and give an example where $\gcd(b,c) > g$.

---

Solution: $g = \gcd(a, b) \implies g | b \implies b=g.m_1$

$g = \gcd(a, c) \implies g | c \implies c=g.m_2$

for some $m_1,m_2 \in \Bbb N$.

Thus $\gcd(b,c) = \gcd(g.m_1,g.m_2) = g. \gcd(m_1,m_2) \geq g$, since $\gcd(m_1,m_2) \geq 1.$

Example: $a = 9, b=6,c=12$. Now $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a, c) = 3$, but $\gcd(b,c) = 6 >3.$

Is the solution correct?

Comment: yes. I think the most simple example is $(1,2,2)$

Comment: $ g$ is a common divisor of $b$ & $c$ because  $g=\gcd (a,b)\implies g|b$ and  $g=gcd (a,c)\implies g|c $. So you could say that $g$ is a common divisor of $b$ & $c$ so $g$ cannot be less than their $least$ common divisor......One way to get $g<\gcd(b,c)$ is to have $a|b$ and $b|c$ with $a<b\leq c,$ so $g=a<b=\gcd(b,c).$... As in the comment from Exodd,

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Is my example correct?

Comment: Yes of course it is. & so is your proof. The first have of my first comment was to show you what I think is a simpler proof.

Comment: In your example $a=9,b=6,c=12,$ you have $b|c$ with $\gcd (a.c/b)=1, $ implying $\gcd (a,c)=\gcd (a,b).$  And you also have $\gcd (a,b)<b.$ So $g<b=\gcd (b,c).$